# Directus custom filter/search with python machine learning

Tags: python, linux, apache, ubuntu, directus

I want to implement my own filter in directus based on python machine learning.

- User posts a message/question to the Server
- Directus save the message/question
- at this moment, a python script search for similar message/question (machine learning)
- Directus answers with the answer found by the python script

Is this possible ?

How can I implement something like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd have to use [Hooks](https://docs.directus.io/extensions/hooks.html#create-a-hook). Hooks allow you to run any arbitrary code when certain events happen in the system. When a user posts something new, you would pass along the posted message to your python script.